# arr.Append() vs. arr.Push() in ColdFusion

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2021

What is the difference between

```
<cfscript>
   i = []
    
   i.push(1)

   i = []

   i.append(1)
</cfscript>
```

?

They both seem to have the same results.

Comment: OT: Since append() seems to contain all of the same functionality of push() - and more - kind of makes you wonder what was the need for adding push()?

Comment: @sos, I think they are just trying to make Coldfusion similar to Javascript syntax.

Comment: @rrk - Yeah, I'd figured something like that, but still doesn't sound particularly useful to create multiple functions that do the same thing :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to James A. Mohler's answer where the return value is different for each function, there's another distinction between the two.  For `append()`, there's also an additional optional boolean parameter `merge` which if set to `true` (default) will merge to the source array.  If false, it will add the array as an additional element at the end.  For your example of appending a single element to the array, setting the `merge` parameter to either true or false changes nothing.  However, if you're appending 2 arrays together, the difference is clear.  For example

```
<cfscript>
   i=[1,2,3,4,5];
   i.append([6,7], true);
   writeDump(i);

   i=[1,2,3,4,5];
   i.append([6,7], false);
   writeDump(i);

   i=[1,2,3,4,5];
   i.push([6,7]); // Works the same as append(..., false);
   writeDump(i);
</cfscript>
```

#### EDIT (from James A. Mohler's comment)

Results
`i.append([6,7], true);` [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
`i.append([6,7], false);`  [1,2,3,4,5,[6,7]]
`i.push([6,7]);` [1,2,3,4,5,[6,7]]

You can see the gist [here](https://trycf.com/gist/b61f74fdeadc95ae44fc2e23035c5c25/acf2018?theme=monokai).

Comment: I see that `push` works similar to append(.., false)

Comment: @JamesAMohler Indeed.  I'll update my answer to reflect that observation.

Answer (score 4):

If you run this

```
<cfscript>
    
    i = []
    
    writedump(i.push(1)) // returns array length
    writedump(i.append(1)) // returns array
    
</cfscript>
```

You can see that they give different responses.

[image]